Why does GCC put a gap before the virtual memory address of .init_data in shared objects

Apparently, there's always a gap before .init_array in shared objects. Is this just a convention? I can't find any reference on it.

If my main program loads too many SO's, htop shows a notable increase in the virtual memory space usage. It seems quite misleading, although I think it has zero real-world consequences since the gaps are only virtual and wouldn't be referenced and thus paged into physical memory?

Also, the size column doesn't match the actual disk space. My guess is that the total size in the size column doesn't account for padding between the segments/sections.


Minimal example for gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609, for the following command. It's the same in other systems I've tried.
Content in foo.c
#include <stdio.h>


void foo(void)
{
    puts("Hello, I am a shared library");
}

gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fpic -g3 foo.c
gcc -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o

I get the following output when inspecting the SO file.
❯ size -A -d libfoo.so
libfoo.so  :
section               size      addr
.note.gnu.build-id      36       456
.gnu.hash               60       496
.dynsym                336       560
.dynstr                172       896
.gnu.version            28      1068
.gnu.version_r          32      1096
.rela.dyn              192      1128
.rela.plt               24      1320
.init                   26      1344
.plt                    32      1376
.plt.got                16      1408
.text                  275      1424
.fini                    9      1700
.rodata                 29      1709
.eh_frame_hdr           28      1740
.eh_frame              100      1768
.init_array              8   2100736
.fini_array              8   2100744
.jcr                     8   2100752
.dynamic               448   2100760
.got                    40   2101208
.got.plt                32   2101248
.data                    8   2101280
.bss                     8   2101288
.comment                53         0
.debug_aranges          48         0
.debug_info            145         0
.debug_abbrev           69         0
.debug_line            424         0
.debug_str           15511         0
.debug_macro          4020         0
Total                22225

❯ l -l libfoo.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 28936 Apr 17 18:48 libfoo.so*


You can check the linker script by passing -Xlinker --verbose option to gcc. I checked and it says . = DATA_SEGMENT_ALIGN (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE), CONSTANT (COMMONPAGESIZE)) before the .init_array, which may be the cause.

@kakkoko pointed me to the right direction. I found this post also digging into the same problem.
The reason is that the linker would want to share the text section in shared libraries and not share the data section which comes afterward. So to ensure it's safe to share the text segment among multiple executions of the program, the linker would put the data section at the same offset in the next page.
The article queries: "That doesn’t really explain why the desired address is the same offset in the next page, rather than simply the start of the next page. It may be as simple as that having originally been the easy thing to do (originally) and the logic stuck." Ian Lance Taylor 's explanation:

There is a reason that we skip to the next virtual page at the same
offset.  I touch on it in https://www.airs.com/blog/archives/45 though
I guess it's not very clear.  By using the same offset, the linker can
use the same page in the file for the end of the text segment and the
start of the data segment.  That page winds up getting mapped twice:
one read-only and executable as part of the text segment, and once
read-write as part of the data segment.  This saves space in the file,
and if we're lucky it makes the file one page shorter.

That's a brilliant trick. If I were asked to calculate the offset in the virtual page, given that text and data are next to each other on the same physical page, barring padding for alignment, I might get to the offset formula. Yet it'd be hard for me to come up with the trick the other way around :).

I'm glad my comment was useful for you. Note that the default value of MAXPAGESIZE in x86_64 has been changed to 4KB in binutils 2.40, so smaller gaps would appear in newer environment.
